# How can I create a sharing option on Feedly?

Tags: api, sharing, google-reader, feedly

I'm working on a product that helps users store links using hashtags and being able to act on them later (i.e. add tasks based on that article).

So I'm looking to building an extension for Feedly so that people can push an article to our website. But I have no idea where to start or how to do it.

http://developer.feedly.com/v3/entries/

I saw their developer site, but the API is to access content, can't find anything about adding a sharing option. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this is a point of extension feedly offers publicly.  You'll need to contact them about integration with your app.

Comment: It seems you are right...I guess they don't want people to flood the users with the option/

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use Greasemonkey (Firefox plugin) or Tampermonkey (Chrome plugin) for this. For example, I wrote a script in Javascript so that I could import articles from feedly into Mendeley, a reference manager. I then installed this script using Greasemonkey; now it runs right after my feedly page loads whenever I visit the site in "Title Only" view, and modifies the sharing capabilities of the feedly page. Perhaps you can modify this script so users can push feedly articles to your website: [feedly2mendeley.js](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/292038)